# MalformedInputException: Input length = 1 while reading text file with Files.readAllLines(Path.get("file").get(0);

Tags: encoding

Why am I getting this error?  I'm trying to extract information from a bank statement PDF and tally different bills for the month.  I write the data from a PDF to a text file so I can get specific data from the file (e.g. ASPEN HOME IMPRO, then iterate down to what the dollar amount is, then read that text line to a string)

When the `Files.readAllLines(Path.get("bankData").get(0)` code is run, I get the error.  Any thoughts why?  Encoding issue?

Here is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\wmsai\\Desktop\\BankStatement.pdf");
    PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("bankData"));
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("bankData"));
    String pdfText = stripper.getText(Loader.loadPDF(file)).toUpperCase();

    bw.write(pdfText);
    bw.flush();
    bw.close();

    LineNumberReader lineNum = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader("bankData"));
    String aspenHomeImpro = "PAYMENT: ACH: ASPEN HOME IMPRO";
    String line;
    while ((line = lineNum.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.contains(aspenHomeImpro)) {
            int lineNumber = lineNum.getLineNumber();
            int newLineNumber = lineNumber + 4;
            String aspenData = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("bankData")).get(0); //This is the code with the error
            System.out.println(newLineNumber);
            break;
        } else if (!line.contains(aspenHomeImpro)) {
            continue;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out.  I had to check the properties of the text file in question (I'm using Eclipse) to figure out what the actual encoding of the text file was.

Then, when creating the file in the program, encode the text file to UTF-8 so that Files.readAllLines could read and grab the data I wanted to get.